How to scan multiple SonarQube projects using api/measures/component
I am using a groovy script in Jenkins in order to scan issues for a specific project. If I include just one project name in the 'component="project_name"', it returns the specific metric keys that I am calling without issue. However, I want to use the same method for scanning multiple projects. Is there a way to do this using the api/measures/component API, or do I need to be using a different one?
I have tried adding the additional project names separated by a comma, but the job fails saying that the component is not found. I am expecting the metric keys to be returned for multiple projects.
